# wait_until timeout causing only one thread to terminate, unable to catch all thread timeouts

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, mutex, condition-variable

I've made a simple thread-safe `Buffer` implementation, creating 10 threads to work on the `buffer` queue to push and pop randomly some numbers. My implementation should let threads that are waiting to pop to wait only for 3 seconds and then terminate. When that occurs I print a timeout message.

The problem is that only one timeout message is printed, the main will then join all threads and return. Why?

Here is the code, main.cpp

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "Buffer.h"

int main() {

    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
    Buffer<std::string> buffer(3);

    srandom(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        workers.emplace_back([&buffer]{
            long num = random();
            if(num%2==0) {
                std::stringstream msg;
                msg << std::this_thread::get_id() << " pushing " << num << std::endl;
                std::cout << msg.str();
                buffer.push(std::to_string(num));
            } else {
                std::stringstream msg1;
                msg1 << std::this_thread::get_id() << " waiting to pop" << std::endl;
                std::cout << msg1.str();
                std::string popped_string = buffer.pop();
                std::stringstream msg2;
                msg2 << std::this_thread::get_id() << " popped " << popped_string << std::endl;
                std::cout << msg2.str();
            }
        });
    }

    for (auto &w: workers) {
        if (w.joinable()) w.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Buffer.h

```
#ifndef PDS_CPP_BUFFER_H
#define PDS_CPP_BUFFER_H

#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

template <class T>
class Buffer {
private:
    std::queue<T> queue;
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::chrono::seconds sec;
public:
    Buffer(int time) : sec(time), queue() {};

    void push(T object) {
        std::lock_guard lockGuard(mutex);
        this->queue.push(object);
        this->cv.notify_one();
    }

    T pop() {
        std::unique_lock uniqueLock(mutex);
//        this->cv.wait(uniqueLock, [this]{ return !this->queue.empty(); });
        if(this->cv.wait_for(uniqueLock, this->sec, [this]{ return !this->queue.empty(); })) {
        } else {
            std::stringstream msg;
            msg << std::this_thread::get_id() << " timeout" << std::endl;
            std::cout << msg.str();
        }

        T object = this->queue.front();
        this->queue.pop();
        uniqueLock.unlock();
        return object;
    }
};


#endif //PDS_CPP_BUFFER_H
```

Comment: It is unknown how many pushes and pops in this code because of `random`. Hence, it is hard to specify the expected result. It is possible that all threads do `push` and none does `pop`.

Comment: Does it successfully joins or just crashes?
        T object = this->queue.front();
In case of timeout this will attempt to access not existing elements, since queue is still empty, leading to UB, which means basically any behavior.

Comment: @alexrider it successfully joins